# How do I cancel all running queries in serverless redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift-serverless

My serverless redshift has thousands of running queries. I think it is stuck. I'm not sure how to cancel all queries and start fresh. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 8):

Since STV_RECENTS is not available in serverless endpoint, you can get all the running queries with

```
SELECT * FROM SYS_QUERY_HISTORY WHERE status = 'running'
```

, the session_id is the PID

Then you can cancel them with

```
CANCEL <session_id>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this correct answer friend! You just saved us a lot of work re-doing the logic in our applications.

Answer (score -1):

From [CANCEL - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CANCEL.html):

> Cancels a database query that is currently running.
>
> ```
> CANCEL process_id [ 'message' ]
> ```
>
> The CANCEL command requires the process ID of the running query and displays a confirmation message to verify that the query was cancelled.
>
> To cancel a currently running query, first retrieve the process ID for the query that you want to cancel. To determine the process IDs for all currently running queries, type the following command:

```sql
select pid, starttime, duration,
trim(user_name) as user,
trim (query) as querytxt
from stv_recents
where status = 'Running';
```

See also:

- [PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND.html) that terminates a session
- [Terminate (kill) specific session on a server - Amazon Redshift Data Dictionary Queries](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/amazon-redshift/kill-session)

Comment: Thanks. I want to cancel all running queries. Do you suggest writing a script which iterates the process ids?
Is there another way to do it?

Comment: You can't run stv_recents on a serverless endpoint. You can run sys_query_history, but that doesn't give you the pid that you need to run pg_terminate_backend(pid).